# arangodb hello-foxxx sample application installation in OSX

Tags: arangodb

I'm trying to run the 'hello-foxx' example on my Mac OSX 10.10.5 Yosemite but fail.

- ArangoDB is installed and running (from the App store)
- Foxx-Manager runs (typing foxx-manager returns the response as described in the manual)
- The anrangodb web interface runs (but w/o the 'application' menu

When I execute:foxx-manager install hello-foxx /example
from my home directory I receive the following error:
'Cannot call method 'byExample' of null'

I also tried to run it directly from git:
foxx-manager install https://github.com/arangodb-foxx/demo-hello-foxx.git /example
returns the same error.
tried a local installation and received the same error.

Any ideas?
I can't find the log files. Where should I look?

Many thanks.

Comment: Which version of ArangoDB do you use?

Answer (score 1):

The app store version is three versions behind the current release. I recommend installing Arrangodb with Homebrew instead. I did this yesterday and had no problems with Foxx Demo on Yosemite.